Using Gate Threshold as Overvoltage Protection
I need to charge my lithium battery using TP4056 via a 5 W solar panel, open circuit voltage on that solar panel can reach 21 V, TP4056 can only handle a max voltage of 8 V.
I was thinking of looking at Gate Threshold vs Rds(on) curves of MOSFET I have and choose one that will keep voltage of solar panel limited to 7 or so voltages using itself to dissipate extra power as heat and then TP4056 can further pull those voltages down to safe levels underload as it can only deliver 0.30 A at Pmax.
Will it work as crude but sturdy overvoltage protection?

a lot of FETs won't like a 21v vgs, so it depends. an lm317 would be more reliable, as vgs(th) can crawl around a bit with temp and per-unit.

21V seems a little mismatched for Vmpt at 80% to drive a low voltage.

A 21 Voc panel has Vmp of around 15V.
Imp amd Isc are very similar.
Run the panel at much lower Vout than Vmp and the most current you get is about Isc. So running it at 7V gives about 7/15 =~ 45% of rated Vmp. Ideally you want a MUCH lower Vmp rated panel to get most of rated power.
Your shorting scheme will work in general principal but unless you use a FET rated at FAR more dissipation look carefully at the datasheet SOA (Safe operating are) curves.  A properly dissipation  and resistance rated resistor in the drain can help move heat out of the FET.
TL431 is very useful i this application BUT Vmax varies - be sure that the ones you have work acceptably at max applied voltage. (TLV431s may be 18V rated. TL431 usually around 36V. Others exist).

After reading your answer I realized that being greedy by using bigger solar panel might even be worse than using 6v smaller panel, my best bet now would be to add a microcontroller in the mix to make my setup smart so it only runs when required

@asim  You need a panel with Vmax and Vmp matched to your requirement. Rather than using an about 15C 5W panel you could use a say 6V, 15w panel. The TP4056 boards typically are limited to 1A charge rate so a 6V, 6W panel is about all you need. In very low light a higher wattage panel will make more power than a low wattage one so an eg 6V 15W panel would be useful in low light situations.

Probably not: the gate curve is not very sharp (Id vs. Vgs), nor is it well defined (varies a volt or two due to manufacture).
A zener diode however would work just fine here, and a 5W zener diode such as 1N5342 is readily available from many sources, or a "boosted zener" such as a 1N5235 into TIP31,

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
with a heatsink on the transistor, would do just fine.  Most any heatsink-package BJT will do here.

I knew a zener would be the ans but I will have to order them from different source as they are not readily available in my country, I do have decent amount of TL431 handy

TL431 can also be boosted. Have you checked the datasheet for ideas?
